# QVector<int> writing/resize performance

Tags: c++, qt

I was trying to refactor some code that use C-style vector of integers to QVector (as the rest of code use Qt).
Before I do that, I made performance tests to check how bad this change would be.

I uses this code:

```
#include <QVector>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>
#include <ctime>

void test1(int MAX_ELEMENTS, int TIMES) {
    int vec[MAX_ELEMENTS];
    int nelems = 0;
    for (int j=0; j<TIMES; j++) {
        nelems = MAX_ELEMENTS;
        for (int i=0; i<MAX_ELEMENTS; i++)
            vec[i] = 2;
    }
    printf("Vec[0] = %d\n", vec[0]);
}

void test2(int MAX_ELEMENTS, int TIMES) {
    std::vector<int> vec;
    vec.reserve(MAX_ELEMENTS);
    for (int j=0; j<TIMES; j++) {
        vec.clear();
        for (int i=0; i<MAX_ELEMENTS; i++)
            vec.push_back(2);
    }
    printf("Vec[0] = %d\n", vec[0]);
}

void test3(int MAX_ELEMENTS, int TIMES) {
    QVector<int> vec;
    vec.reserve(MAX_ELEMENTS);
    for (int j=0; j<TIMES; j++) {
        vec.clear();
        for (int i=0; i<MAX_ELEMENTS; i++)
            vec.push_back(2);
    }
    printf("Vec[0] = %d\n", vec[0]);
}

void test4(int MAX_ELEMENTS, int TIMES) {
    QVector<int> vec;
    vec.reserve(MAX_ELEMENTS);
    for (int j=0; j<TIMES; j++) {
        vec.resize(MAX_ELEMENTS);
        for (int i=0; i<MAX_ELEMENTS; i++)
            vec[i] = 2;
    }
    printf("Vec[0] = %d\n", vec[0]);
}

double measureExecutionTime(void (*func)(int, int)) {
    const int MAX_ELEMENTS=30000;
    const int TIMES=2000000;
    clock_t begin, end;
    begin = clock();
    (*func)(MAX_ELEMENTS, TIMES);
    end = clock();
    return (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}

int main() {
    double time_spent;
    time_spent = measureExecutionTime(test1);
    printf("Test 1 (plain c): %lf\n", time_spent);
    time_spent = measureExecutionTime(test2);
    printf("Test 2 (std::vector): %lf\n", time_spent);
    time_spent = measureExecutionTime(test3);
    printf("Test 3 (QVector clear): %lf\n", time_spent);
    time_spent = measureExecutionTime(test4);
    printf("Test 4 (QVector resize): %lf\n", time_spent);

    return 0;
}
```

And the results were:

```
Vec[0] = 2
Test 1 (plain c): 16.130129
Vec[0] = 2
Test 2 (std::vector): 92.719583
Vec[0] = 2
Test 3 (QVector clear): 109.882463
Vec[0] = 2
Test 4 (QVector resize): 46.261172
```

Any ideas on a a different way in order to increase the QVector performance?
This vector is filled from 0 to its new size few times per second (it is used in a timetable scheduling software).

---

Qt version: 5.7.1(+dsfg1, from Debian testing).

The command line I used to compile from a Linux shell:

```
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -I. -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5 -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore -I. -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -o teste.o teste.cpp
```

And to be clear: the vector elements are not equal, I just put them equals 2. The number of valid elements in vector keeps changing as the number of activities of timetable are successfully scheduled - When a given activity cannot be placed in the remaining slots, the algorithm starts rolling back, removing some of the last placed activities in order to start another try of scheduling.

Comment: *And the results were:* -- And the compiler options used to build the test are...?  In other words, if you're timing an unoptimized build, your findings are worthless.

Comment: If performance is time critical, you shouldn't allocate and then clear a QVector (or any container, really) in the time sensitive part of your code.

Comment: If you want to create a vector full of 2's, the fastest way is probably `std::vector<int> vec(MAX_ELEMENTS, 2);`. Now you are comparing apples to oranges.

Comment: All this is a moot point if you happen to be using Visual Studio and running a "debug" build.  The reason is that `vector` is notoriously slow due to iterator checks in the debug build.  That's why it's important to state what are the optimizations used when asking about performance.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, OK, sorry I forgot these info are important to state. Post edited.

Comment: @BoPersson, I could use random(), but I put 2 due to laziness ;) But in the actual program they are not random values.

Comment: @MrEricSir I just want to avoid to use two variables as the author's original code do: one for "real size" (number of valid elements) and another for the array itself. Without an extra class/struct.

Comment: @RodolfoRG - We are a bit sensitive here. :-) If you post in the [tag:c++] tag and state that C++ is a lot slower than C, you must show **real** code to support that. Because we know that `std::vector` performance is generally +/- a few percentage points from a C style array in real benchmarks. And not always +. So a performance ratio of .98 or 1.02 I would believe, but not .17

Comment: @BoPersson - I don't to create a war between C and C++ :-) The real code has a ton of... legacy. But here it is.

https://github.com/rodolforg/fet/blob/upstream/src/engine/generate.cpp#L2954

I'm trying to "modernize" a open source code that is not mine.
Variable is difficultActivities  (and its "pointer"/element counter nDifficultActivities)

Comment: @RodolfoRG ok.  Numbers not so meaningless now.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Your test is not comparing apples to apples.

- `int vec[MAX_ELEMENTS]` will be allocated on the stack, while `std::vector` and `QVector` will use the heap. Stack-based allocation is much faster. If you can get away with stack-based allocation consider `std::array`.
- if you just interested in filling the vector with values, try to benchmark only this part.

---

In other words, try to benchmark:

```
for(int i = 0; i < max_size; ++i)
    c_array[i] = i;
```

vs

```
std_vector.resize(max_size); // <- initialization, not benchmarked
for(int i = 0; i < max_size; ++i)
    std_vector[i] = i;
```

vs

```
qvector.resize(max_size); // <- initialization, not benchmarked
for(int i = 0; i < max_size; ++i)
    qvector[i] = i;
```

The performance should be fairly similar.

Comment: The resizing happens a lot. I edited the original post adding some clarification, I hope.

I changed the program in order to remove the .reserve() methods from the benchmark. The results did not change.


Test 1 (plain c): 16.044388

Test 2 (std::array): 16.055172

Test 3 (std::vector): 91.533684

Test 4 (QVector clear): 112.354447

Test 5 (QVector resize): 41.223804

Comment: I also realized that the resize() is not interfering in performance, because I call it everytime using the same argument (so, it should do nothing at all). I tested it, and it spent a similar time.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, as [MrEricSir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2146682/mrericsir) pointed out in the comments section, the `clear()` operation is the real culprit in `test4`.

If you check the Qt documentation you find the following:

> void QVector::clear()
>
> Removes all the elements from the vector.
>
> Note: Until Qt 5.6, this also released the memory used by the vector.
> From Qt 5.7, the capacity is preserved.

You may be using Qt version < 5.7 which forces the release of memory within the loop.

Comment: Sadly, it is 5.7.1 (from Debian testing package)

Answer (score 0):

The test is pretty much nonsense to begin with, and not just nonsense, but poorly implemented at that. Especially in terms of testing resizing, with a static size raw C array. How does that test resizing without any resizing taking place? And even for the containers that use any resizing, you are resizing to the already reserved value, which shouldn't have any effect, since your `MAX_ELEMENTS` never varies throughout the test.

That being said, for such trivial operations `QVector` is more than likely to suffer from being a COW. That is Qt's implicit sharing for containers, with Copy-On-Write, meaning that each non-const method executed will do a check if the container data is being shared in order to detach it if that's the case. That check involves atomics, which involve synchronization, which is expensive.

If you were to execute more adequate test for write access, such as this:

```
  int elements = 30000, times = 200000;
  QElapsedTimer t;

  int * ia = new int[elements];
  t.start();
  for (int it = 0; it < times; ++ it) {
    for (int ic = 0; ic < elements; ++ic) {
      ia[ic] = 2;
    }
  }
  qDebug() << t.elapsed() << " msec for raw array";    

  QVector<int> iqv(elements);
  t.restart();
  for (int it = 0; it < times; ++ it) {
    for (int ic = 0; ic < elements; ++ic) {
      iqv[ic] = 2;
    }
  }
  qDebug() << t.elapsed() << " msec for qvector";

  std::vector<int> isv;
  isv.reserve(elements);
  t.restart();
  for (int it = 0; it < times; ++ it) {
    for (int ic = 0; ic < elements; ++ic) {
      isv[ic] = 2;
    }
  }
  qDebug() << t.elapsed() << " msec for std::vector";
```

you'd see results that very much resonate with what's been said above, on my system the results are:

```
1491  msec for raw array
4238  msec for qvector
1491  msec for std::vector
```

The times for a raw / C array and `std::vector` are practically identical, while `QVector` languishes.

If we were to test reading by accumulating the container values the situation is reversed, note that in this case we are using `at(index) const` for `QVector`:

```
2169  msec for raw array
2170  msec for qvector
2801  msec for std::vector
```

Without the penalty of COW `QVector` has performance identical to a raw C array. It is `std::vector` that loses here, although I am not sure exactly why, maybe someone else can elaborate.

Comment: I don't want to test the vector writing solely. I do need to "resize" it. I'm sorry I did not myself clear. As a non-native english speaker, I avoid to write too much.

Reading performance is irrelevant to me: what is done exhaustively is writing - and changing the array/vector size.

Comment: If you are interest in resizing, why are you testing the raw C array with a static size? How is that a measure of anything? Resizing in any of the cases will involve heap reallocation and copying of data, so it should be pretty much identical between the different solutions. So in terms of convenience plus optimal writing speed it seems that `std::vector` is the right choice.

Comment: By "Resize" I meant changing the number of valid elements.
That's why I used reserve() methods for Qt and std vectors, trying to pre-allocate the maximum number of elements.
Qt docs[1] says that QVector::resize() does not shrink the vector capacity. So I thought that would not be a problem when doing it repeatedly.
[1] http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html#resize

Comment: Well in that case you are not doing any resizing, you are just using a different size of the available space.